# Return a Link from PHP to Android to download

Tags: php, android, download

After connecting Android App to PHP and verifying the order then issuing the download link I need to return this download link as is to Android to read it and starts download.

From PHP side I have the result ends

```
echo ''.$url.'/used/'.$products.'/'.$orderid.'.dat';
```

From Android (JAVA) side:

```
                  int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
  String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
  String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

  String query = "purchaseData="+purchaseData+"&dataSignature="+dataSignature+";   
  final String url = "https://domain/thankyou.php?" + query;



        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error in verification Please make sure !!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }else{
                             Download_file(response);

                        }


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })

        };
```

Edit clarify question:
My question how return the link as is from echo of PHP to JAVA so Android Download Manager can read it and start downloading

Comment: You need to clarify what your question is.

Comment: My question how return the link as is from echo of PHP to JAVA so Android Download Manager can read it and start downloading

Comment: Just a comment, this opens up huge loopholes...  Imagine if your app gets MITM'ed and the attacker sends back a malicious link.  Android would download it without question.  I suggest rethinking your design.

Comment: @luke-park thanks for the suggestion. I'm using INAPP purchase data and custom string to verify order as the file won't be issued if the these parameter don't meet. Do you think this isn't enough?

Comment: Well if the whole communication is MITM'ed then what stops the attacker from just changing the URL?  The client would have no way of telling that it has been modified, even if everything else is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right thus what you suggest? As I couldn't find Google InApp Billing API to communicate with and verify orders. I had to do it the easy way going to complete the project